# Why my "Copy picture of selected area to the clipboard" does not work as usual?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, screen-capture

macOSX 10.13.6

I am frustrated with screenshot capture shortcut on my MacOS X.  It becomes a camera icon and it only captures the window rather than area selection, like the following picture.

[image]

I did not change anything, and I have no idea why it suddenly works like this.  The original function should look like this:

[image]

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You can switch between area/window screenshot with spacebar.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek, can you answer it below, and I can mark it as the correct answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch between area/window screenshot with a spacebar. [Here's the Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361) website about the screenshots.